# Efficient method for looking for the closest point

Tags: geometry, transformation

I have $N$ points ${P_1, P_2, P_3, ..., P_N}$ with dimension $K$, where $K\gg N$. Given another point $Q$ with the same dimension, I want to get which of is the point $P_n$ which is closest to $Q$. The solution is easy, but since I want to perform the operation multiple times and using the fact that $K\gg N$ I am looking for a way to transform ${P_1, P_2, P_3, ..., P_N}$ and $Q$ to a lower dimension which could give the same result with less storage and computation. Is this possible?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Yes, it is always possible to squeeze them to a space of dimension not greater than $N-1$: think at what happens to $3$ points in 3-D, you can always put them on a 2-D plane.

Comment: One can pre-structure a graph for rapid search:  See  https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1012-a-rapid-graph-based-method-for-arbitrary-transformation-invariant-pattern-classification.pdf

Comment: Could try PCA. How well it works will depend on the specific dataset though and how orthogonal the $P_n$s are.

Comment: When you say you will have to perform it multiple times, do you mean that  you will keep the $P_n$ points and make the test for different $Q$ points ?

Comment: Try to do it first with two and three points in 2, 3, and 4 dimension. IT seems that for any N points N-1 dimension (different from the original set) will suffice.